# kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation doesn't work properly in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, core-location, cllocationmanager

1. Add "location" into the project's plist file.
2. Allocate and initialize the location manager.

   `self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];`

   `[self.locationManager setDelegate:self];`

   `[self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];`

   `[self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];`

   `[self.locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:NO];`

   `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`
3. Implement the delegate function.

   `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{ }`

It works perfect in the foreground. I want to make it called frequently in the background as same as foreground. But it doesn't.

Please help me what should I add more.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is better you read the documentation 
[here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)
Second, with iOS7, there is a chance that user can disable location updates in the Settings menu of iPhone. Hence you should check `backgroundRefreshStatus` property available in UIApplication class inside AppDelegate method `applicationDidBecomeActive`. If the user denied permission, then this value gets set to `UIBackgroundRefreshStatusDenie`. So you should request the user to give the permission via an alert.

Answer (score 1):

You say, "Add "location" into the project's plist file."

Do you mean you have added "App registers for location updates" in the "Required background modes" of -info.plist?

Are you doing this manually, or selecting "Location Updates" under the "Background Modes" section of "Capabilities" for your target?